# Cannot drop to all areas of a div that has been transformed by CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop, transform

I'm trying to develope a Drag & Drop function. The droppable div is transformed by CSS. The draggable div won't drop on the shown box, it just drops left beside and in the middle of the box but won't drop on the right part of the box.

Here's a simple version of the page's code, plus a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t5e2qvgt/8/

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();
$("#droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
      .find("span")
      .html("Dropped!");
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

#droppable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

.droptarget {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg, 0);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg, 0);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg, 0);
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg, 0);
  transform: skew(45deg, 0);
}

.droptargeticon {
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="droppable" class="droptarget ui-widget-header">
  <div class="droptargeticon">
    <p>Drop here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag</p>
</div>
```

Comment: After the skew transform jquery-ui recognizes the contet-box as a box with the original width and height, and no transform, but starting from the upper left corner of the now transformed box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bad implementation of the content-box of the element being transformed with skew in the browser. You assume the browser understands the new transformed context box, but id doesn't.

```
$('#droppable').outerWidth() // 189
```

Clearly the width is larger than `189`, in fact `189` is the width of the element **withouth the skew transform**

The position **is** changed

```
// With transform
$('#droppable').position(); // { top: 0, left: 189 }

// Without transform
$('#droppable').position(); // { top: 0, left: 357 }
```

All the transform seems to be doing with the content-box in the DOM is change the position to the upper left corner of the skewed element, nothing else, so it does not represent the shape of the element you see.

This is probably a limitation in the browser and the DOM that you won't be able to fix :(

Using raw JavaScript instead of jQuery has the same results, so it's not jQuery.

You could try to use a wrapper as a droppable, and put the skewed element inside, but the droppable area will be a bigger square.

**EDIT**

I actually reported this as a bug to Chromium, you can see the [discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-discuss/Yu000WT34Ck/discussion). They basically told me to request it to the W3C so the standarize it and we get it in all browsers. I'm not going that far, feel free to do it yourself.